# unable to create instance for UITableViewCell in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am using tableview to list my products. In "cellForRowAtIndexPath", with the help of "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier", we can access property of UITableViewCell. For Example,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell1 = product_tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productmain", forIndexPath: indexPath) as product_tblCell

cell1.label1.text = "PRODUCT 1"
return cell1
}
```

but, if we want to use outside of this scope, within this viewController itself, how can we access that UITableViewCell property?

If I create like this any of UIButton action in this viewController,

```
var prop_cell = product_tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productmain") as product_tblCell 

prod_cell.label1.text = "PRODUCT 5"
//NO ERROR SHOWN. BUT FATAL ERROR IN DEBUG AREA.
//UNABLE TO RUN
```

I am getting fatal error.
This is my major doubt in UITableView. Kindly response this. Don't simply De-Vote. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the first place. This cell, even if it's correctly dequeued, won't ever appear in your table view, so why set label1's text? You'll never see it. You should explain why you're trying to do this.

Comment: Logic: UIButton, UILabel in Tablecell, dragged from Storyboard. Totally 5 Rows. So 5 buttons, 5 labels. If I press 3rd row's button, that LABEL's text alone should be change. then, If we press 2nd button, that LABEL's text alone change. But, that button action should be in UIViewController, not in UITableViewCell. @rdelmar

Comment: Yes, but you don't dequeue a cell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath to accomplish that. You use addTarget:action inside cellForRowAtIndexPath to make the controller (self) the target of the button's action. You can either give the button a tag equal to the indexPath.row, or you can get the indexPath from the table view method indexPathForRowAtPoint to figure out which row the button was in.

Comment: func to_wish_list(sender : UIButton) 
{ 
var img = UIImage(named: "wish_2.png") 
sender.setImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
sender.enabled = false 
}
Button inside the cell,, I have added target for that, which I declared in "cellFor RowIndexPath". That will call this func. Exactly button image is changing. But, if I scroll the tableview, automatically another button images also changed. I don't know how and why? Do u know the reason? Hope you understand my doubt.

Comment: You have that problem because you aren't accounting for cell reuse. If you don't understand that, then you can't use a table view correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the real question is why do you want to dequeue/access the cell? 
I think maybe you want to update your cell label, maybe you want to update 'Product 1' name to 'Product 5'
For this you need to figure out which indexPath has 'Product 1' and use the following code.

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Give it the indexPath and it will return you the tableViewCell.

You can create your own NSIndexPath with

```
init!(forRow row: Int,
   inSection section: Int) -> NSIndexPath
```

Comment: Logic: UIButton, UILabel in Tablecell, dragged from Storyboard. Totally 5 Rows. So 5 buttons, 5 labels. If I press 3rd row's button, that LABEL's text alone should be change. then, If we press 2nd button, that LABEL's text alone change. But, that button action should be in UIViewController, not in UITableViewCell. @iosDev82

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two methods as well.

Method 1:

Adding **tags** to cell while creating and retrieve the cell  using the same tag.

You can add tag as follows

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell1 = product_tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productmain", forIndexPath: indexPath) as product_tblCell

    cell1.label1.text = "PRODUCT 1"
    cell1.tag = 1
    return cell1
}
```

and retrieve like this

```
func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var cellTag:Int = 1;//this is same at table cell row number.
    var cell = self.tableView.viewWithTag(cellTag) as UITableViewCell
    cell.label1.text = "PRODUCT 5"
}
```

Method 2:

Using flag

Set a flag on the button click and then reload the table data

```
func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    isButtonTapped = true
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

On reloading the table view

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell1 = product_tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productmain", forIndexPath: indexPath) as product_tblCell

    if(isButtonTapped){
       cell1.label1.text = "PRODUCT 5"
    }else{
       cell1.label1.text = "PRODUCT 1"
    }
    return cell1
}
```

Method 3:

Create a custom UITableViewCell class and, handle the button clicks in UITableViewController by using custom cell delegate methods

for reference, check this out for Crafting Custom UITableView Cells in Storyboard.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Comment: Logic: UIButton, UILabel in Tablecell, dragged from Storyboard. Totally 5 Rows. So 5 buttons, 5 labels. If I press 3rd row's button, that LABEL's text alone should be change. then, If we press 2nd button, that LABEL's text alone change. But, that button action should be in UIViewController, not in UITableViewCell. @ Karthi

Comment: Are the 5 rows are static?

Comment: No. It may increase. Dynamic only.

Comment: For your requirement, you have to create a custom UITableViewCell class and, handle the button clicks in UITableViewController by recognising the  UITableViewCellDelegate methods.

Comment: Check this out for reference. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431538/uibutton-inside-uitableviewcell-facing-image-changing-issue-while-tableview-get    This is my major doubt @karthi. That only I have solved.