# UIButton inside UITableViewCell facing image changing issue while tableview get scrolled

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I am doing "Add to favourite Page" using SWIFT. In my product list table, "Wish" button is there. That button is dragged from Storyboard. If User clicks the button, that image change to another new one. I did upto this part, exactly working too. But, if we scroll the tableview, automatically another cell button image has been changed to new one. I don't know how and why? How to solve this? Kindly guide me.

```
//MY CODING IS BELOW
unc tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell1 = product_tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productmain", forIndexPath: indexPath) as product_tblCell
           image_url = arrayFromJson[indexPath.row].valueForKey("image_url") as NSString
           let imgurl = NSURL(string: image_url)!
           var imgdata : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgurl)!
           prod_img = UIImage(data: imgdata)!

           id = String(arrayFromJson[indexPath.row].valueForKey("id") as NSInteger)
           code = arrayFromJson[indexPath.row].valueForKey("code") as NSString
           descrip = arrayFromJson[indexPath.row].valueForKey("description") as NSString
           name = arrayFromJson[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as NSString
           price = String(arrayFromJson[indexPath.row].valueForKey("price") as NSInteger)

           cell1.name.text = name
           cell1.prod_desc.text = descrip
           cell1.prod_price.text = price
           cell1.prod_image.image = prod_img


           cell1.wish_image_but.addTarget(self, action : Selector("to_wish_list:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

           return cell1
}

func to_wish_list(sender : UIButton)
   {
           var img = UIImage(named: "wish_2.png")
           sender.setImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
           sender.enabled = false
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you scroll the tableview and your cell goes beyond visible boundry, it is used for displaying another data. And when it has comes back is visible boundry it's data is set again.

That means, you have to check if the cell has been marked for "to_wish_list" while setting cell data. if yes then set the UIImage(named: "wish_2.png") by default else set defult image.

Comment: How to do that? Any idea?